# Data Science Cookie Cutter: How to keep multiple versions of raw files

Tags: makefile, data-science, cookiecutter

Using the data science [cookiecutter](https://github.com/drivendata/cookiecutter-data-science), how is it possible to keep multiple versions of raw files?

More precisely, if I have two files

```
data/raw/scrape_2017_06.json
data/raw/scrape_2017_04.json
```

How can I assure that `make` always uses the newest version?

Comment: Are we talking about a specific Makefile or just Makefile in general?

Comment: rather in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can relay on file names and sorting those files in `raw/data` by names in lexical order is equivalent of sorting them by their age, following solution would be enough:

```
DATAFILE:=$(lastword $(sort $(wildcard data/raw/*.json)))

all:
    @echo The latest datafile is $(DATAFILE)
```

If not, you need to rely on operating system commands. For Unix system many implementations (certainly, the GNU one) support -t to sort by modification time. So it would be:

```
DATAFILE:=$(firstword $(shell ls -t data/raw/*.json))
```

Comment: Can I use DATAFILE as the dependency of a target?